# how to select a pin via a function and refocus to the InfoWindow of that pin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have a map with a lot of pins. Right now when a user clicks on a pin the viewing window automatically moves to center on the pin.

I want the user to see a list of locations which have been pinned. When they click on a location in the list, the map automatically centers to the pin and opens up the InfoWindow. So I basically want to have the same functionality of a user clicking on a pin, but without having them physically clicking on it. I want to do it through a function call.

Each pin obviously has a unique ID number which I've set.

So maybe something like:

```
$("#locationOnList-17").on("click", function(pinID) {
  // What could go in here to mimic a physical pin click and have it center and open the InfoWindow? I don't think I would even need to invoke the map.setCenter(location) function.
};
```

EDIT:

Ohhhhh... I think I found something: [Maps Example](http://www.easypagez.eu/maps/basicmap.html)

```
  function myclick(i) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
  }
```

So you assign an ID number to the pin, and then you make the function above and pass in the ID number and user the google.maps.event.trigger function to mimic a click. That's what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
addMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(PoiLat, PoiLon),
    html: 'any Information',
    map: map
});

infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(addMarker, 'click', function(event) {

        infowindow.setContent("<div class=infoWndw style=height:160px;width:360px>" + this.html + "</div>");
        infowindow.open(map, this);
    }
});
```